# Getting a random value from an enum class variable

Tags: java

Say I have the following, arbitrary example enums:

```java
public enum Season {
    SPRING, SUMMER, AUTUMN, WINTER
}

public enum WeekDay {
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY
}

public enum Direction {
    UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
}
```

Now, in a project I'm working on, I'm using the following code to get a random value of an enum (which I need when a config-file does not specify one). For example:

```java
if (this.direction == null) {
    this.direction = Direction.values()[new Random().nextInt(Direction.values().length()]);
}
```

This works fine, but I'm coming to a point where lots of duplication for this code is showing up:

```java
if (this.direction == null) {
    this.direction = Direction.values()[new Random().nextInt(Direction.values().length()]);
}
if (this.season == null) {
    this.season = Season.values()[new Random().nextInt(Season.values().length()]);
}
if (this.weekDay == null) {
    this.weekDay = WeekDay .values()[new Random().nextInt(WeekDay .values().length()]);
}
[...]
```

What I'm now looking for, is to make a utility class/method, which is capable of doing this for any enum, eliminating the code duplication. The end result should look something like this:

```
if (this.season == null) {
    this.season = EnumUtil.getRandomValue(Season.class);
}
```

There are a couple of things I have tried, but I never got past the point where my IDE (IntelliJ Community) would stop highlighting everything in deep red warnings. Something like:

```java
public static <clazz> clazz getRandomValue(@NotNull Class<Enum<?>> e) {
}
```

... is the direction I tried to go in, but all I'm hitting is dead ends.

Comment: Please always include the exact code you tried (and "feel best" about), including the exact error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a generic parameter to your method, so you can return the desired enum type:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> E getRandomEnum(Class<E> clazz, Random r) {
    E[] constants = clazz.getEnumConstants();
    return constants[r.nextInt(constants.length)];
}
```

I also added a `Random` parameter, so you can reuse the same `Random` instance, as you should.

```
Random random = new Random();
if (this.direction == null) {
    this.direction = getRandomEnum(Direction.class, random);
}
if (this.season == null) {
    this.season = getRandomEnum(Season.class, random);
}
if (this.weekDay == null) {
    this.weekDay = getRandomEnum(WeekDay.class, random);
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note: one can also just shuffle the array, and pick the first one. Probably a bit less code, but a performance penalty.

Comment: Thank you, that looks to be just it! Totally agree with implementing the random like that and i appreciate the detail on your end. In this case however i already have a `public static final Random SHARED_RANDOM` in my main class. Maybe i should've noted that in my example code.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to each enum where you need it the method `getRundom()` for example:

```
public enum WeekDay {
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY;

   private Random random = new Random();
   public static WeekDay getRandom() {
      return values()[random.nextInt(values().length()]);
   }
}
```

After that anywhere you need it just use

```
WeekDay.getRandom();
```

And so on to each enum where you need it

Comment: That's a good idea, but it comes with the precondition that i am only doing this with enums that i created and thus have access to editing/expanding - which isn't the case

Comment: OK, I see. You can create an EnumWrapper class that has an enum property and a method random() which is implemented in your wrapper class but not inside the existing enum

Comment: Is `getRundom()` an intentional pun, or did you mean `getRandom()`?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, no that was just a stupid typo on my part, fixed now